# Convert this string to timestamp PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime, date-conversion

I have this string: "13/10 15:00" and I would like to convert it to timestamp but when I do this:

```
      $timestamp = strtotime("13/10 15:00");
```

It returns an empty value.

Comment: strtotime isn't infallible - if you know the format, you should use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (available from PHP 5.3.x and above) or similar. (You'll also need to provide the missing year.)

Comment: Your format is not supported! http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

Comment: your string is not a well defined date or time

Comment: and you can use this `Carbon::create(2022, 1, 21, 10, 00, 00)`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In your code `strtotime()` is attempting to convert `13/10` as the tenth day of the 13th month, which returns an error.

If you want to parse a date string with a custom format, it's better to use DateTime::createFromFormat() instead:

```
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m G:i", "13/10 15:00");
$timestamp = $dtime->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: `$timestamp` variable contains DateTime object, not timestamp. To get timestamp, use `$timestamp->getTimestamp();` or `$timestamp->format('U');`

Comment: @Glavić True enough - still more reliable than `strtotime()`. Thanks.

Comment: Link to documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 28):

```
  $timestamp = strtotime("13-10-2013 15:00");
```

This can be important:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
> the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
> slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
> separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
> is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
> dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

https://www.php.net/strtotime