# Converting String to Time without the date in php

Tags: php

I am parsing the string "11:00 PM" to the database. I want to convert the string to military time as 23:00 and write to the database.

I tried with the below:

```
$traveltime = "11:00 PM";
$contraveltime = date(strtotime("%H:%i",'$traveltime'));
```

I get the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
Filename: views/addtrip_individual.php
Line Number: 332
```

Line 332 is where the second code line is.

How do I make this work?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert this string to timestamp PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346858/convert-this-string-to-timestamp-php)

Comment: Also irrelevant, 23:00 is not military time it's 24h time. 2300 is military time.

Comment: This >>> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 5):

The format argument belongs in the `date` function, not in `strtotime`. And you need to eliminate the single quotes around `$traveltime`, or you'll just be evaluating the literal string '$traveltime'. Also, the `%` characters shouldn't be used in the format string. Those are used for `printf`, etc. and aren't required here.

```
$contraveltime = date("H:i", strtotime($traveltime));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please start with looking at the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual. One simple way, that I would use is:

```
echo date("G:i", strtotime("3:00 PM"));   // 15:00
```

Since `1500` is a military time, not `15:00`, you might need to do:

```
echo date("Gi", strtotime("3:00 PM"));    // 1500
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do some think like

```
// 24-hour time to 12-hour time 
$time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30"));

// 12-hour time to 24-hour time 
$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("1:30 PM"));
```

Ref link :[How do you convert between 12 hour time and 24 hour time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742191/how-do-you-convert-between-12-hour-time-and-24-hour-time-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the error is just the way you call the functions
try this way

```
$traveltime = "11:00 PM";
$contraveltime = date('H:i', strtotime($traveltime));
```

Comment: thanks! this worked , I just positioned the elements wrongly!

Answer (score 0):

Its show error because date function first parameter must date format

but you given strtotime function

for correct result please follow below code

```
$traveltime = "11:00 PM";
$contraveltime = date('H:i',strtotime($traveltime));
echo $contraveltime;
```

and out put will be like below code

```
23:00
```

now you store $contraveltime into database