# convert date and time from textbox into timestamp in php

Tags: php

I currently have a date/time picker that puts the current date and time the user selected into a textbox.

The format is like the following :

22-04-2018 17:34
d-m-Y H:i

I am wondering if there is a way to convert that into a PHP timestamp?

Comment: Read https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346858/convert-this-string-to-timestamp-php

Comment: If you can choose format I suggest using Y-m-d instead as it's easier to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, the best option is to choose a "Y-m-d" format as that can easily be converted to timestamp with strtotime().
But if you can't do that you can use datetime class to convert it.

```
$time = "22-04-2018 17:34";
$format = "d-m-Y H:i";

$dt = date_create_from_format ($format , $time);
Echo date_timestamp_get($dt);
```

https://3v4l.org/eWdWN